# Spliting the screen Using co-ordinates or pixel with the help of css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to know is there a way to define the space in the screen using pixel or x,y co-ordinates. I can specify multiple coordinates to have more space like a Tiles and would like to load the data in that.

Is there any plugin available? Or Is there any other idea is also appreciatable.

Thanks